# Does service workers support server sent events?

Tags: service-worker, server-sent-events

Can someone tell me if service workers (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/)  support server sent events (SSE)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the service worker specification's [issue tracker](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/885), service workers should be able to intercept [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource).

That being said, I've never seen an example of a service worker that did anything meaningful with [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events).

Comment: Haven't checked if it works in practice, but maybe it could be used for fanning-out messages in case of many tabs, since the `EventSource`s are very limited per origin.